# unable to form structure and filter out the values based on flag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the structure like expectedOutput by iterating tabs data and filter out the data when flag is true

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag:false},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag: true},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag: false}]}


let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [,
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue',flag:true},
                    ]}

let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).map(([tab,data]) => {
    data = data.map(d => ({...d}));
    data.filter(d => d.flag == true)
    return [tab,data];
  })
);

console.log("original",tabs);
console.log("new",newTabs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**filter doesn't change the original array, it just returns filtered array**

```
let tabs = {
'tab1': [{id: '1', mnemonic: 'first', value: 'jim', flag: false},
    {id: '2', mnemonic: 'second', value: 'kim', flag: true}],
'tab2': [{id: '1', mnemonic: 'first', value: 'jim', flag: true},
    {id: '2', mnemonic: 'second', value: 'kim', flag: false}]
}


let expectedOutput = {
'tab1': [,
    {id: '2', mnemonic: 'second', value: 'kim', flag: true}],
'tab2': [{id: '1', mnemonic: 'first', value: 'newValue', flag: true},
]
}

let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
   Object.entries(tabs).map(([tab, data]) => {
     data = data.map(d => ({...d}));
    // filter doesnt change the original array, it just return filtered array
    data = data.filter(d => d.flag === true)
    return [tab, data];
})
);

console.log("original", tabs);
console.log("new", newTabs);
```

Comment: suppose if the filter value is true and need to remove the id field from it like let expectedOutput = {
'tab1': [,
    {mnemonic: 'second', value: 'kim', flag: true}],
'tab2': [{mnemonic: 'first', value: 'newValue', flag: true},
]
}, how can i achieve this

Comment: you can use `.map` that: `data = data.map((d)=>{delete d.id; return d;})`

Comment: let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag:false},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag: false},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag: false}]}assuming if flag is true only for tab1, instead of having tab2  has empty array,is it possible to have only tab1 details

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the filtered data to the object that gets created. Your current `.filter` creates a new filtered array that isn't used anywhere; the old array does not get mutated.

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag:false},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag: true},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag: false}]}


let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [,
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue',flag:true},
                    ]}

let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).map(([tab,data]) => [
    tab,
    data.filter(({ flag }) => flag)
  ])
);

console.log("new",newTabs);
```

Comment: answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

```js
let tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag:false},
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim',flag: true},
                    {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag: false}]}


let expectedOutput = {'tab1': [,
                     {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim',flag:true}],
            'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue',flag:true},
                    ]}

let newTabs = {};
Object.entries(tabs).map((item) => {
  newTabs[item[0]] = item[1].filter(({ flag}) => flag === true);
});

console.log("original",tabs);
console.log("new",newTabs);
```

Comment: map is not returning anyting